# How url works with or without trailing slash using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess in my PHP website. I want to work url with or without trailing slash.

Below code works only with the trailing slash.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

e.g. **www.mydomain.com/index/ --Works** 
     **www.mydomain.com/index  --Not Work**

If anybody know how can I get this without trailing slash?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want to match it regardless of `/` in the end use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will stop reapplication of same rule since `$1.php` will be a real/valid file.

Comment: Hello, I have also used `ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php` in same htaccess but it is not working in other words its not redirecting to not-found page it show 'Internal Sever Error'.

Comment: hi, can you tell me how can I figure out this issue? This issue has came after I put the above code in htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks, it works. One another question is this code works for the url like 'www.mydomain.com/service/servicename/'? And how can use url which is non case sensitive?

Comment: If you have a php file with the name `service/servicename.php` it will work. Case doesn't matter since capturing regex is `.+?`

Answer (score 0):

Put a `?` after the `/` to make it optional.

Answer (score 0):

Fix would be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with something similar

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```